# How to compile .java files in terminal?

Tags: java

I have already installed JDK in my 12.04, but i don't know how to compile .java files in Terminal.
I used `javac FILENAME.java` then `java FILENAME` in terminalbut this shows error like this

javac: file not found: sum.java

Usage: javac

use -help for a list of possible options

Answer (score 1):

Your current working directory in the terminal needs to be the same directory that has the sum.java file in it. The `cd` command is used to change directories in the terminal. Then the usage is the same as you wrote in your question, and it's also in: [How to run a Java program in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321754/how-to-run-java-program-in-ubuntu-in-following-situtations/321755#321755) if you want to see another example.