# Installation of jdk from tar.gz file

Tags: 15.04

i have downloaded the jdk file having the `tar.gz` extension.I am using a 64 bit pc.but i don't understand how to install the `javac` compiler and how to set the path in Ubuntu 15.04.if anyone can give me step by step process please.

Comment: And what's about `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Comment: See this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps

Comment: javac compiler -- [How to run a Java program in Ubuntu in the following situations](http://askubuntu.com/questions/321754/how-to-run-a-java-program-in-ubuntu-in-the-following-situations)