# I get no output when I compile Java code from the Terminal

Tags: command-line, java, compiling, gedit

When I try to run my Hello World program it doesn't show any output:

```
$ ls
hello.class hello.java 
$ javac hello.java
$
```

Comment: I thought`javac` was just the compiler, then once it's compiled you run your program with `java`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a Java program in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/321754/how-to-run-a-java-program-in-ubuntu)

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @terodactyl fixed

Answer (score 18):

You can see from `ls` that you already compiled your program with the compiler `javac`. The command you used

```
javac hello.java
```

creates `hello.class` without sending any output to stdout, so there won't be any messages in your terminal unless there are errors - what you see is the expected behaviour. If you actually want to see some output, you can add an option: `javac -verbose hello.java` as mentioned by @Frisky (thanks!)

Now you can run that file `hello.class` with

```
java hello
```

Comment: @Zannas answer is correct. But, if you just want to see some output, you can use the -verbose option.