# Can't run java program with terminal in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: command-line, java, openjdk

I can't run any java program with terminal:

[image: Screen shot of the error]

```
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And where is the command that gave this error?

Comment: Down in screenshot, i use command "java" to run javafile.

Comment: Compile first before running, and you're using an IDE so use that to compile and run it. Images of this sort aren't advised copy and paste!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubutnu. Learn to use javac, and java. Or just use IDE to run.

Comment: I'm using Intellij, but i need to learn some terminal commands, who can help me in the future :) I was reading about java and javac commands, but totally forgot about that packages are not folders :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get no output when I compile Java code from the Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797025/i-get-no-output-when-i-compile-java-code-from-the-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile Java source code (usually with a file ending in `.java`) you need to enact the Java Compiler, a.k.a. `javac`.  This compiles the source to a bytecode binary file ending in `.class`.

When *running* bytecode binaries, you refer to the **full classname**, not the file.  Java will then look for the appropriate `.class` file **relative to the current location**, load the appropriate class, and call the function `main()`.  This allows there to be many (even nested) callable starts to a program from the one compiled binary classfile.

Furthermore, Java classes can exist in *packages* which are organised by directory, and declared at the top of the file, e.g.

```
package Arrays;
```

So, once you have compiled your program, you need to be in the folder *above* the Arrays folder, and then remove the `.java` from your java command and prefix the classname with 'Arrays.'. e.g.

```
$ cd /path/to/src
$ java Arrays.Speeds
```

Comment: I try this, but the error is same https://imgur.com/a/sTjDPeC

Comment: I missed that your application is in a `package Arrays`.  I have updated my answer to the correct way to call packaged classes.

Comment: Effectively the same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433366/running-java-in-package-from-command-line#19433387

Comment: It's work, thanks. I forgot that Arrays is package and I use it like a folder...