# openjdk-8-jdk Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: jdk

***[image: strong text]***

i have installed openjdk-8-jdk from synaptic package manager and want to run java programs on my ubuntu (16.4)  terminal  shows me this kind of error:could not find or load java class file
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a Java program in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/321754/how-to-run-a-java-program-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the code first:

```
javac table.java
```

this will create the file `table.class`. This is the executable program, which you can run like so:

```
java table
```

(without the `.class` extension)

Comment: ** you helped me out**  thanx buddy