# how do I use java applets with Firefox

Tags: java

Can someone please show me how I can use/install a java applet I downloaded to work with my browser (firefox).
The applet is BNCApplet.java that I got from this link:

http://world.std.com/~reinhold/BigNumCalc.html

I have installed openjdk using:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

And tried to compile by:

```
javac BNCApplet.java
```

which gave me loads of error messages that mean nothing to me. Here it is:

```
javac BNCApplet1.java 

BNCApplet1.java:51: error: class BigNumCalc is public, should be
declared in a file named BigNumCalc.java public class BigNumCalc 
       ^ Note: BNCApplet1.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note:
BNCApplet1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile
with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 1 error
```

I am sure this java program is bug-free and should work flawlessly. In any case should I be compiling this at all before I can use it as a plugin? And how do I use it as a plugin.

Update: I have also installed icedtea as suggested by Byte Commander:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-8-plugin
```

and checked it in firefox preferences and it is there and active.

When I File/Open the BNCApplet.java in firefox it simply offers to save the file!

I badly need a step-by-step insrtructions to install this applet.
Thanks

Comment: That source code is from the year 2000. Something has probably changed in Java that prevents it form compiling.

Comment: what about the process? should it be compiled before it can be used as an applet?

Comment: Yes, code **must** be compiled before you can run it. (The notable exceptions being scripting languages, like Bash)

Comment: Thanks for that. Sounds like we are not going to get anywhere with this. Let's not waste any more time on this useless program and close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

A `.java` file is a Java source code file, which is a plain text document. It is not executable.

To run it, you would have to install a JDK (Java Development Kit) like the `openjdk-8-jdk` package, if you don't have one already:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

After that, you can use the Java compiler `javac` to compile the source code `BNCApplet.java` file to a byte code `.class` file:

```
javac BNCApplet.java
```

After that, you can run the compiled `BNCApplet.class` file using the `java` command, but without the `.class` suffix:

```
java BNCApplet
```

Further reads about how to compile and run `.java` files on Ubuntu:

- [How to run a Java program in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321754/how-to-run-a-java-program-in-ubuntu)
- [How to compile and run .java files in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420591/how-to-compile-and-run-java-files-in-ubuntu)

---

I'm not 100% sure, but this way Applets should run in a separate Applet Viewer window. To be able to run Java Applets in your browser if you use an OpenJDK Java implementation, you need the additional IcedTea package that provides a browser plug-in for Firefox-like (NPAPI) browsers. Oracle Java already includes this plug-in.

To install the plug-in for OpenJDK 8, run:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-8-plugin
```

Comment: I installed openjdk as you suggested and tried compiling -- this is how it went: $ javac BNCApplet.java 
BNCApplet.java:8: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
 Copyright � 2000 Arnold G. Reinhold, Cambridge. MA USA
           ^
1 error -- (the hat sign points to the character before 2000)

Comment: Please edit your questions to provide this information, comments are not well suited for output, as they don't preserve formatting. They also might be deleted for several reasons. And the issue you're pointing out has something to do with the character encoding of the Java source code. The easiest fix would probably be to to open the file in a text editor and remove that offending character, probably it's a © somewhere in a comment line or in a string, which shouldn't affect the program.